# Split String with more than one character in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, split, separator

I've read the other threads but they only seem to deal with single character delimiters, and I think Playground is crashing for me because I use more than one char.

```
"[0, 1, 2, 1]".characters
              .split(isSeparator: {[",", "[", "]"].contains($0)}))
              .map(String.init) //["0", " 1", " 2", " 1"]
```

kinda works but I want to use " ," not ",". Obviously I can use [",", " ", "[", "]"] and that throws out the spaces but what about when I want only string patterns to be removed?

In brief: How do I separate a Swift string by precisely other smaller string(s)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Swift 5**

```
let s = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let splitted = s.split { [",", "[", "]"].contains(String($0)) }
let trimmed = splitted.map { String($0).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) }
```

**Swift 2**

```
let s = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let charset = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
let splitted = s.characters.split(isSeparator: {[",", "[", "]"].contains($0)})
let trimmed = splitted.map { String($0).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(charset) }
```

Result is an array of Strings without the extra spaces:

> ["0", "1", "2", "1"]

Comment: Thanks. So are we saying that there is no Swift solution, only Obj-C ones?

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities spring to mind. If you can use characters as separators:

```
let str = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let separatorSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ",[]")
let comps = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separatorSet).filter({return !$0.isEmpty})
```

This yields

> ["0", " 1", " 2", "1"]

If necessary, the spaces can be removed by either mapping with `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` or by adding a space to the `separatorSet`.

Or if you really need to use strings as separators:

```
let str = "[0, 1, 2, 1]"
let separators = [", ", "[", "]"]
let comps = separators.reduce([str]) { (comps, separator) in
    return comps.flatMap { return $0.componentsSeparatedByString(separator) }.filter({return !$0.isEmpty})
}
```

Which yields:

> ["0", "1", "2", "1"]

Comment: By copying and pasting your first code directly I got ["0", " 1", " 2", " 1"] which is half the problem I have, Swift hates spaces.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right. My bad. You can either run each through `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` or add a space to the `NSCharacterSet`. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.